# dbt Snowflake select column with space

Tags: dbt

I have a table (non dbt model) in Snowflake created by another team. All of the column have a  space. Example : "Sales Date".

I use the double quote to select the column, it works if I run the query in Snowflake. But after run it in dbt, it shows an error like this:

> 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 9 at position 21
> invalid identifier '"Sales Date"'

I tried to compile the dbt model and run it in Snowflake, it works also. I don't understand why dbt add another single quote, so I can't execute the dbt run.

This is my code:

```
SELECT *  FROM {{ source('amc_dsp_idn', 'vw_f_amc_idn_daily_sales') }}
WHERE YEAR("Sales Date") >= 2024
```

Comment: Did you enable quoting in your config? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/quote

Comment: no, I don't enable quoting

Comment: I tried to run the same script this morning without a config change, and IT WORKS! I don't know how; maybe it's just a glitch.